# REST resource collection with different entity types

Tags: rest

It is stated in REST philosophy that if you have different types in the same resource(`/ads`) collection, list only same columns.

```
    {
        "ads": {
            "meta" {
                "count": 1899
            },
            "data" [
                {
                    "type": "tractor",
                    "make": "Ford"
                    "model": "",
                    "moto_hours": "50"
                },
                {
                    "type": "car",
                    "make": "Audi"
                    "model": "A4"
                    "moto_hours": ""
                 }
            ]
        }
    }
```

However i have a question, maybe it is valid to do and this way?

```
    {
        "ads": {
            "meta" {
                "count": 1899
            },
            "data" [
                {
                    "type": "tractor",
                    "make": "Ford"
                    "moto_hours": "50"
                },
                {
                    "type": "car",
                    "make": "Audi"
                    "model": "A4"
                 }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is, do you want your users to have to check if the field exists or not? That's between you and your users. The business reason to do that is if there's a semantic difference between "" and no value (null).

Comment: Yes, i want to let them check, and this is possible in the second example, but theirs schema differs.. so maybe it's not the best solution to do this way?